# Como hago para que se cierren las ventanas al pulsar un cierto botón en mi sistema de prolog?

Tags: prolog, xpce

Lo que pasa es que estamos haciendo un sistema experto en Prolog y mi ejemplo es de Horóscopo, en mi caso te pide elegir tu fecha de nacimiento y te tira que signo eres, pero las ventanas con las preguntas solo se cierran al pulsar el botón "No", si eliges tu fecha de nacimiento en la ventana principal te aparece el signo pero la ventana de pregunta continua abierta y luego los botones ya no funcionan, les dejo mi código para ejecutarlo y si pueden ayudarme, debo entregarlo mañana a la noche es urgente, me dan puntos extras si lo entrego conectado a una base de datos, pero el problema de las ventanas es lo que más quiero ayuda, se los agradeceria muchisimo.

PD: Lo que está en comentario es por que como dice, hacia la pregunta dos veces y no quise borrarlo entonces lo dejé así.

```
:-use_module(library(pce)).%llama libreria pce.
:-use_module(library(pce_style_item)).

main:-
    new(Menu, dialog('DESCUBRE DE QUE SIGNO ERES')),
    new(L, label(nombre,'HOLA, BIENVENIDO A LA PRUEBA DE HOROSCOPO')),
    new(@texto, label(nombre,'Responde con tu fecha de nacimiento y el programa te dará tu resultado:')),
    new(@resp1, label(nombre,'')),
    new(Salir, button('SALIR', and(message(Menu, destroy), message(Menu,free)))),
    new(@boton, button('REALIZAR PRUEBA', message(@prolog, botones))),

    send(L, font, font(lucida_fax, bold, 30)),
    send(@texto, font, font(calibri, calibri, 20)),
    send(@resp1, font, font(lucida_fax, bold, 20)),
    send(Salir, font, font(calibri, calibri, 15)),
    send(@boton, font, font(calibri, calibri, 15)),

    send(Menu,append(L)),new(@btncarrera, button('consulta?')),
    send(Menu,display,L,point(125,20)),
    send(Menu,display,@boton,point(100,150)),
    send(Menu,display,@texto,point(20,100)),
    send(Menu,display,Salir,point(20,400)),
    send(Menu,display,@resp1,point(20,130)),
    send(Menu,open_centered).
%lo que está en paréntesis es la respuesta
signos(aries):-aries,!.
signos(tauro):-tauro,!.
signos(géminis):-géminis,!.
signos(cáncer):-cáncer,!.
signos(leo):-leo,!.
signos(virgo):-virgo,!.
signos(libra):-libra,!.
signos(escorpio):-escorpio,!.
signos(sagitario):-sagitario,!.
signos(capricornio):-capricornio,!.
signos(acuario):-acuario,!.
signos(piscis):-piscis,!.

%esto hacia que se haga la pregunta dos veces
%aries:-signo_aries,
   % pregunta('confirma tu respuesta').

%tauro:-signo_tauro,
   % pregunta('confirma tu respuesta').

%géminis:-signo_géminis,
    %pregunta('confirma tu respuesta').

%cáncer:-signo_cáncer,
    %pregunta('eres del signo cáncer').

%leo:-signo_leo,
    %pregunta('eres del signo leo').

%virgo:-signo_virgo,
    %pregunta('eres del signo virgo').

%libra:-signo_libra,
    %pregunta('eres del signo libra').

%escorpio:-signo_escorpio,
    %pregunta('eres del signo escorpio').

%sagitario:-signo_sagitario,
    %pregunta('eres del signo sagitario').

%capricornio:-signo_capricornio,
    %pregunta('eres del signo sagitario').

%acuario:-signo_acuario,
    %pregunta('eres del signo acuario').

%piscis:-signo_piscis,
    %pregunta('eres del signo piscis').


aries:-pregunta('21 de marzo al 19 de abril'),!.
tauro:-pregunta('20 de abril al 20 de mayo'),!.
géminis:-pregunta('21 de mayo al 20 de junio'),!.
cáncer:-pregunta('21 de junio al 22 de julio'),!.
leo:-pregunta('23 de julio al 23 de agosto'),!.
virgo:-pregunta('24 de agosto al 22 de septiembre'),!.
libra:-pregunta('23 de septiembre al 22 de octubre'),!.
escorpio:-pregunta('23 de octubre al 21 de noviembre'),!.
sagitario:-pregunta('22 de noviebre al 21 de diciembre'),!.
capricornio:-pregunta('22 de diciembre al 19 de enero'),!.
acuario:-pregunta('29 de enero al 19 de febrero'),!.
piscis:-pregunta('20 de febrero al 20 de marzo'),!.

:-dynamic si/1,no/1.

preguntar(Problema):- new(Di,dialog('HOROSCOPO')),
    new(L2,label(texto,'Elige tu fecha de nacimiento:')),
    new(La,label(prob,Problema)),
    send(L2,font,font(arial,arial,15)),
    new(B1,button(si,and(message(Di,return,si)))),%and(message(Di, destroy), message(Di,free))))),
    new(B2,button(no,and(message(Di,return,no)))),%and(message(Di,destroy),message(Di,free))))),

    send(Di,append,(L2)),
    send(Di,append(La)),
    send(Di,append(B1)),
    send(Di,append(B2)),

    send(Di,default_button,si),
    send(Di,open_centered),get(Di,confirm,Answer),
    ((Answer==si)->assert(si(Problema));
                             assert(no(Problema)),fail).
    pregunta(S):-(si(S)->true;(no(S)->fail;preguntar(S))).
limpiar:-retract(si(_)),fail.
limpiar:-retract(no(_)),fail.
limpiar.

botones:-lim,
    send(@boton, free),
    send(@btncarrera,free),
    signos(Sign),
    send(@texto, selection('De acuerdo con su fecha de nacimiento eres del signo:')),

    send(@resp1,selection(Sign)),
    new(@boton,button('Iniciar su evaluación',message(@prolog,botones))),
    send(Menu,display,@boton,point(40,50)),
         send(Menu,display,@btncarrera,point(20,50)),
         limpiar.
         lim:-send(@resp1,selection('')).
```

Comment: Buenas noches... los enlaces a un monton de codigo no son bienvenidos. Si queres nuestra ayuda, deberias construir un ejemplo minimo y verificable, y poner el codigo aqui.

Comment: Está bien muchas gracias, no sabia como hacerlo.